# Views - getting Title field from other content types via entity reference

Tags: 7, entities, views

I have two content types: `speaker` and `session`. Session has an entity reference field to speaker - when you create a session, you add references to one or more speakers.

I need to create a view of speakers and details from the speaker nodes, but also include the titles of the sessions that they're referenced on. I've added a relationship using the type `Entity Reference: Referencing entity - A bridge to the Content entity that is referencing Content via field_speaker`, and when I go to add new fields, I can see all of the fields from the session content type EXCEPT Title. The only Content: Title that's available is the one from the speaker nodes.

[image]

What do I need to do to get the Content: Title that's on the session node?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should choose the one that says "Content: Title". In the next page you can choose the relationship you want this field's value to come from, i.e. your entity reference field.

e.g.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thank you! So any fields that the two content types might have in common (as far as field names go) need to be selected that way, rather than displaying directly in the list. That makes sense.

Comment: Yeah I think Views is clever enough to group duplicate entries together. I remember it taking a while to figure this out too